# Why am I keeping get this error message? xxx.so undefined reference to `absl::StrCat[abi:cxx11](absl::AlphaNum const& ...)`

Tags: ros

I am keeping get those error messages when I do catkin_make in ROS, Ubuntu 16.04.

`xxx.so undefined reference to absl::StrCat[abi:cxx11](absl::AlphaNum const& ...)`

`xxx.so undefined reference to absl::String_internal::CatPieces[abi:cxx11]`

`xxx.so undefined reference to absl::numbers_internal::FasIntToBuffer(int,char*)`

`xxx.so undefined reference to absl::numbers_internal::SixDigitsToBuffer(double, char*)`

I git clone the abseil.cpp libary from github and `mkdir build` and `install` folder for build and install.
Then `cp` the `install/include` to `usr/local/include`, I also pack all .a files to `libabsl.a` and `cp` to `usr/lib`

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file

`set(absl_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/local/include)`

`set(absl_LIBS "/usr/lib/libabsl.a)`

`find_package(absl REQUIRED)`

`include_directories(...${absl_INCLUDE_DIR})`

`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node   ${absl_LIBS}`

What might have caused those errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: add this line to you CMakeLists.txt `add_definitions("-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0")`, I think this is caused by different G++ version.